# Can number of constraints be less than number of variables in Linear Programming?

Tags: algorithms, linear-programming, simplex

In standard form of LP we have $n$ variable and $m$ constraint. In simplex algorithm we set all non-basic variable to zero and at most $m$ basic variable have positive value.

if $m < n$, then at least $n-m$ variables would be zero. Is it a valid LP problem? Can solve a LP that $m < n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimize $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2$ where $x_1, x_2\geq 0$.

[In the sense of linear programming this would count as a problem with **zero** constrains. In standard form the non-negativity of the variables is always there, so one would rather count the constrains that are equations.]

Comment: does it mean n-m variable must be zero?

Comment: @bhz It depends whether your constrains are already written in standard form. If it is, then yes. It is very common for the number of variables to be large(r) than the number of constrains. This just means that the set of feasible values of the variables is larger. Regardless of this the optimization problem is meaningful.